# Python: find current directory of remote "cmd.exe" processes

Tags: python, command-line, process, taskkill

I write a script that among other things erases certain directory using shutil.rmtree

I have to ensure that no "cmd.exe" is opened in this directory (and blocking me from erasing that directory).

I can do this by killing all "cmd.exe" on the remote computer:

```
process_name = "cmd.exe"
computer_name = "ATACAMA6"
try:
    subprocess.check_call('taskkill.exe /S {} /U admin1 /P abc$ /IM {}'\
                .format(computer_name, process_name))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError: # no matches were found - thats OK!
    pass
```

But I am afraid of killing "cmd.exe" processes that opened in other directories and need to run.
How can I kill only the ones opened in my specific directory?

Comment: Generally, a process.exe will be found as an executable in the directory unless another program(outside the directory) is accessing your directory contents. Would doing a simple sweep through the directory files be sufficient?

Comment: I want to avoid such cmds:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\directory_to_erase>

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear by what you mean by cmd. Do you mean specific processes?

Comment: That program you probably have on: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Comment: So you want to make sure no command prompts are currently working in directories you are trying to remove.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx  lets you see which processes are running which contents. If you can control it via command line, I'm sure you can implement python code to view the processes that are working in your directory.